# BoxShadow and BorderRadius do not appear in IE with Javascript and CSS?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, css, internet-explorer

I got into a trouble that in the SharePoint, the Box-shadow, Border-radius and the showToggle's div tag don't appear in IE, but it runs very well in FF and Chrome.

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

**JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/sndGB**

Here are pics in both IE and FF:

[image: Pic]

Comment: Do you have the same problem in your fiddle? If so, your problem appears to be off-topic since it in essence is not SharePoint related

Comment: **@RobertLindgren**: No, it doesn't. It still works well in IE with no SharePoint, but when I put it in the SharePoint, only FF and Chrome work with my code.

Comment: OK, then I will take a guess that this is SharePoint 2010 or that you are using an old masterpage setting the compability mode in the browser to IE 8!

Comment: Something like "<meta http-equiv=”x-ua-compatible” content=”IE=8″ >"

Comment: **@RobertLindgren**: That's right. I am using SharePoint 2010, but I have no idea about the masterpage. How about that `"<meta http-equiv=”x-ua-compatible” content=”IE=8″ >"`? How can I change it to `IE="11"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to your master pages putting the browser in IE compatibility mode. Look for `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >` in the master page used.

But I'm afraid it is not as easy as changing this, see for example [here](http://www.proactivespeaks.com/2013/09/12/fixing-sharepoint-compatibility-issues-with-internet-explorer-ie-9-and-ie-10/), the people picker acts in a bad way if this is changed.

Also, there is a hotfix you must install for ASP.NET to recognize IE versions greater than 9: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

[Here is a guide](http://xtrmdevtips.blogspot.se/2012/12/enable-css3-in-sharepoint-2010.html) on how you can get around most of the quirks, but it is a rough path! Fortunately this is much easier in SP 2013 if you have the chance to update :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works pretty well. What I have done is that using SharePoint Designer to modify the `content="IE=8"` to `content="IE=11"` with Advanced Mode.

Comment: Great, that should fix the CSS problems! But watch out for the quirks from the links above ;)

Comment: As a quick glance, there are lots of changes but I thought my problem related with CSS. Hence, this led me to modify from `8` to `11`. Besides that, I hope that nothing will go wrong :-)

Comment: Yepp, your problem is fully CSS 3. But you will have some problem with for example the people picker now that you have changed the `content="IE=11"`

Comment: Well, I've never used the people picker yet. Could you please give me more details about that?

Comment: You have it in the first link in my answer